# Estimate spectral radius of operator product

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

In my research problem, I have to estimate the spectral radius of the following operator
$\chi A$ where $\chi$ is a scalar function taking values 0 or 1 and $A$ is an operator. I can compute explicitly all the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^*$ and $A^*A$. The problem is that $A$ is not an selfadjoint nor normal operator and using the norm $\|A\|$ is too rough a approximation.

My question is that is there any stricter estimation of the spectral radius $\rho(\chi A)$? Or can we say that

$\rho(\chi A)\leq\rho(A)$

Thanks for your help.

P.S: In my physical problem, $\chi(x)$ (taking values of 0 or 1) is a function of coordinate $x$ and $A$ is a tensorial convolution operator (e.g Green function). For example $\chi A$ acting on $v$ yields

$(\chi A) v = \chi(x) [A* v(x)] = \chi(x)$$\int$ $A_{ijkl}(x-x')v_{lk}(x') dx'$

Edit: Recently I found a related thread on this subject
[Singular-value inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181093/singular-value-inequalities?rq=1)
There is an inequality on singular values

$\sum s_j(RS) \leq \sum s_j(R)s_j(S)$.

However I still wonder how to apply this theorem if the number of singular values of $R$, $S$ and $RS$ are different

Comment: How does that help with the spectral radius?  The singular values tell you something about the norm, but not about the spectral radius.

Comment: Thanks. I have found that I am wrong. All I need is to find a computable and astricter estimation of the spectral radius to ensure the convergence of my Neumann series.
Now I am thinking about the numerical radius because there is an inequality $\rho(\chi A)\leq r(\chi)r(A)=r(A)$. Supposing that I know the explicit expression of $A $ in Fourier space. How can I compute the numerical radius of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is on a Hilbert space, 
so that your "scalar function" $\chi$ is a self-adjoint projection (which by the spectral theorem is unitarily equivalent to multiplication by a scalar function with values $\{0,1\}$ on $L^2$ of some measure). 
No, we can't say much about $\rho(\chi A)$ compared to $\rho(A)$.  Consider
the $2 \times 2$ case

$$ A = \pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d\cr},\ \chi = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 0\cr}$$

$$\chi A = \pmatrix{a & b\cr 0 & 0\cr}, \ \text{eigenvalues}\ 0,a $$

so $\chi A$ has spectral radius $|a|$.  But for any $a$, the spectral radius of $A$ could be arbitrarily large (e.g. if $b = 0$ and $d$ is large) or could be $0$ (e.g. if $b = -a^2$, $c = 1$, $d = -a$).

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry that I was not more specific. I have edited my post to provide more information. In this case, your answer does not correspond exactly to the problem I am studying since in your counter example $\chi$ must be multiplied with every element in the matrix A.

Comment: $\chi$ is multiplied with every element in the matrix $A$.  Those elements in the first row are multiplied by $1$, those in the second row are multiplied by $0$.

Comment: In the problem, the product $\chi A$ is given by
$$ \chi A = \pmatrix{\chi a & \chi b\cr \chi c & \chi d\cr},$$

where the function $\chi(x)=1$ in the domain $x\in\Omega$ and $0$ otherwise.$x\in R -\Omega$